# How can I use external variables in Python like 'extern int x;' in C?

Tags: python, extern

How can I use external variables in Python, like `extern int x;` in C?

For example,

**main1.py:**

```
from myfunc import print_a 

a = 10 
print a    
print_a()
```

**myfunc.py:**

```
def print_a():
    global a   
    print a
```

Answer (score 11):

Simply re-assign the variable in the module:

```
import myfunc
from myfunc import print_a 

a = 10 

print a

myfunc.a = a

print_a()
```

Otherwise it is not possible.

Rememeber that python treats modules in a way that is quite different from C.
The `import` in python does *not* "copy the contents" of the file in that place,
but it *executes* the code in the given file and creates a `module` object.

The global variable of the module are the `module` object attributes, which can be modified as I've shown. There is no such notion as "global variable" except for built-ins.

---

I'd suggest to refactor your code in such a way that you don't have to modify this global variable at all, moving the code that uses `myfunc.a` from `main1` to `myfunc`.
The fact that you need such global variable is already a code smell that there's something wrong with your code and you should try to fix it.

---

Actually there is a way to affect the "global scope" but it is so hackish that I don't even want to mention it. Trust me: you don't want to use it. If people see your code using such a hack you may be in physical danger.

Comment: But OP wants to use the same `a` variable from `main1`, not just see a copy of it

Comment: @RyanHaining Where do you see a "copy"? In my example I simply add/change a *reference*, which doesn't imply copying anything so changes to the variable in a module are seen in the other module asweel, except when the object is immutable(in which case you shouldn't care for identity anyway).

Comment: you're copying the reference to an immutable type here to `myfunc`.  If the value of `a` changes in `main1` this won't be reflected in `myfunc.a` unless you manually change it there as well each time you change it in `main1`.

Comment: even if it's mutable, reassigning to `a` won't change what it is in `myfunc.a`.  This behavior is wildly different from the `extern`-like behavior OP is asking for.

Comment: @RyanHaining The point of my answer is exactly this: you cannot do so that when you do `a = something` in a module the value changes in the other, hence **you must manually reassign the value to every module every time you want to reassign that variable**. As I said in my answer there is a way to achieve "exactly" the behaviour the OP wants(with a slightly different syntax), but I'm not going to put it here since it could lead people reading the answer to use it, which is something *nobody* wants.

Comment: I don't see this as something anybody would want either.  Having a module depend on another module to set its globals?  However, I think the OP's intention is to access another modules global variables, or share globals across modules.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike C, variables declared at global scope are still limited in scope to the module they are created in, so you need to qualify the name `a` with the module it lives in.

The `global` keyword is used when you are going to *modify* a global variable by reassigning, you do not need it when you are just referencing a global variable.

If you are trying to access a variable of another file, you must import that module, and because of the way your files are structured you have a couple of ways to resolve issues:

Option 1) Move the referencing of `myfunc.print_a` inside of a function and `import main1` inside `myfunc` to see `a`

**main1.py**

```
import myfunc

a = 10 

def main():
    print a    
    myfunc.print_a()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**myfunc.py**

```
import main1

def print_a():
    print main1.a
```

---

Option 2) **recommended** Move the variable(s) into another module and have both `myfunc` and `main1` import it.

**vals.py**

```
a = 20
```

**main1.py**

```
import vals
from myfunc import print_a

vals.a = 10 

print vals.a    
print_a()
```

**myfunc.py**

```
import vals

def print_a():
    print vals.a
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a workaround to this problem by using a common external file.  In this example I am storing an index variable to flag in each application whether a file is being accessed.  The variable indxOpen in ext1.py and indxO in ext2.py are being updated and stored in a common external text file "externalVars.txt"

lead application ext1.py

```
# lead application ext1.py 
 #this alternately flips the value of indxOpen on prime number intervals 
 import time

 def update(d,v1):
      f=open(d+'externalVars.txt','r+')
      f.write(str( v1)) 
      f.truncate()
      f.close()

 # ensure variable is initialised and made available to external apps
 indxOpen = False
 var_dir = "<your external var directory>/"
 try:
      f =open(var_dir+'externalVars.txt','r')
 except:
      f= open(var_dir+'externalVars.txt','w')
      f.close()
 # this alternately flips the value of indxOpen on prime number intervals    
 update(var_dir,indxOpen)
 i = 0
 while True:   
      while indxOpen:
      i += 1
      if (i % 13) ==0:
        indxOpen = indxOpen ^ True
        update(var_dir,indxOpen)
       f=open(var_dir+'externalVars.txt','r+')
       t=f.readline()
       print "app1",t," ",i
       if t=='False':
           print "app1 updated"
           update(var_dir,indxOpen)
           indxOpen = False  
        else:
            time.sleep(1.4)

   while not indxOpen:
       f=open(var_dir+"externalVars.txt","r+")
       t=f.readline()
       print "app1",t
       if t=='True':           
           indxOpen = True          
       else:
           time.sleep(1)
```

ext2.py following application

```
#   ext2.py this alternately flips the value of indxO on prime number intervals but it is         initialised by the lead application
# in this case ext1.py
# python 2.7.12
import time

def update(d,v1):
    f=open(d+'externalVars.txt','r+')
    f.write(str( v1))
    f.truncate()
    f.close()

var_dir = "<your external var directory>/"

# intialise external variable
f=open(var_dir+'externalVars.txt','r+')
t=f.readline()
if t=='True':
    indxO= True
if t=='False':
    indxO= False
i=0
while True:

    while indxO:    
        f=open(var_dir+"externalVars.txt","r+")
        t=f.readline()
        print "app2",t
        if t=='False':
            indxO = False       
            update(var_dir,indxO)
        else:
            time.sleep(1.5)


    while not indxO:
        i += 1
        if (i % 17) ==0:
            indxO = indxO ^ True
            update(var_dir,indxO)
        f=open(var_dir+"externalVars.txt","r+")
        t=f.readline()
        print "app2",t," ",i
        if t=='True':
            indxO = True
            print "apt2 updated"
            update(var_dir,indxO)
        else:
            time.sleep(1.3)
```