# Global values filled with values inside constructor(__init__) are not reflecting in other python module

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

```
I am trying import global variables defined in one script to other script.
```

**main.py**

```
# import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
import sample
expr = ['age < 10', "country == 'China'"]
values = {}
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, age, country) :
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.country = country
        global values
        values['name'] = name
        values['age'] = age
        values['country'] = country

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    name = raw_input("Enter your name:")
    age = int(input("Enter your age:"))
    country = raw_input("Enter your country:")
    user = Test(name, age, country)
    sample.printValExp()
```

**sample.py**

```
import main

def printValExp():
    print(main.expr)
    print(main.values)
    # print(main.Test.name)
```

**O/P:**

```
[root@dev01 dynamic]# python main.py
Enter your name:sunny
Enter your age:14
Enter your country:japan
['age < 10', "country == 'China'"]
{}
[root@dev01 dynamic]#
```

In main.py, I defined 2 global variables

```
--> expr, initialized with list
--> values, as empty dict
```

uninitialized values dictionary, I am populating with user entered details in constructor(**__ init __**)

Though this ***values*** dict is populated in init method of main.py,
when i imported this global variable in other script **sample.py**, it is showing empty there

But when tried to print ***expr***,
which is also global variable intialized while declaring itself in **main.py**,
this is printing expr value(list of strings)

What should I do to get global variable values in other script,
whose values are populated in

```
__ init __
or inside 
if __ name __ == '__ main __' :
```

Comment: For starters, you have a circular import, which can't be good…

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly above is not working,

any explanations are totally welcome

But i have found work-around solution for given problem, where unable to extend the scope
of global variable, whose value is still showing NULL, though its value is populated
in __ init __ ()

I create another file values.py and implement extern variables concept just like in C
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18034946/9384462) to design extern variables concept in python, whiose variable value
will be shared across different files

**values.py**

```
userDict = {}
```

**main.py**

```
import sample
import values


expr = ['age < 10', "country == 'China'"]

class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, age, country) :
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.country = country
        values.userDict['name'] = name
        values.userDict['age'] = age
        values.userDict['country'] = country

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    name = raw_input("Enter your name:")
    age = int(input("Enter your age:"))
    country = raw_input("Enter your country:")
    user = Test(name, age, country)
    sample.printValExp()
```

**sample.py**

```
import main
import values

def printValExp():
    print(main.expr)
    print(values.userDict)
    # print(main.Test.name)
```

**O/P:**

```
[root@dev01 dynamic]# python main.py
Enter your name:sunny
Enter your age:15
Enter your country:japan
['age < 10', "country == 'China'"]
{'country': 'japan', 'age': 15, 'name': 'sunny'}
```